# If $P(X\leq x') = a$ and $P(X\leq x'') = b$ where $b>a$. Is it always true that $x'' >x'$?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $X$ be a random variable.
If $P(X\leq x') = a$ and $P(X\leq x'') = b$ where $b>a$. Is it always true that $x'' >x'$?

Comment: Try using proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either $x''<x'$ or $x''=x'$ or $x''>x'.$

If $x''=x'$ then $b=\Pr(X\le x'') = \Pr(X\le x') = a.$

The probabilities above are equal because the event $\{X\le x''\}$ is the same as the event $\{X\le x'\}.$

If $x''<x'$ then
\begin{align}
a = {} & \Pr(X\le x') \\[8pt] = {} & \Pr (X\le x'' \text{ or } x''<X\le x') \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(X\le x'') + \Pr(x''<X\le x') \\[8pt]
= {} & b + \Pr(x''<X\le x') \\[8pt]
\ge {} & b. 
\end{align}